# gojs - adding port controllers

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a node template in go.js with a "topArray" that might contain a several ports like in [this](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html) example.

For each top port I want to add a "controller" item - a small clickable rectangle  with a text by it's side, positioned about 10 pixels above each port. The controller object has some requirements:

1. Moves together with it's corresponding port (and node)
2. May be dragged upwards to about 100px above it's port, and downwards to about 10px above it's port. Yet, should move with it's node.
3. Is not included in the fromSpot calculation. The fromSpot of the port should be the top size of the port Shape only.
4. When a link is connected to the port - the controller disappears, yet keeps it's properties.
5. The controller text is editable

This is how a Node with a few ports and controllers looks like (This example is from the script-editor of Virtools)

[image: Virtools script editor]

How can I implement such a part?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement each itemTemplate to be a Spot Panel containing the port (with a **GraphObject.portId** binding) and a dashed line Shape and a TextBlock.  You will need to make the containing Panel force the item Panels to overlap, in order to ignore the width of the TextBlock when deciding how to position those item panels next to each other.

You will need to adapt the http://gojs.net/latest/extensions/PortShiftingTool.js so that it works on those TextBlocks within those item Panels, and so that it only allows vertical movement within a desired range.  That tool should also adjust the length of the dashed line between the TextBlock and the port Shape.

Implement **Node.linkConnected** and **Node.linkDisconnected** event handlers to count the number of connected links and then appropriately set the **visible** property of the TextBlock and the dashed line Shape.

Editable text comes naturally -- just set **TextBlock.editable** to true and use a TwoWay Binding.

Comment: Thanks! And what should be the `toSpot` of this itemTemplate?

Comment: Each item Panel will no longer be a port, but will contain a port, so it will no longer have a **toSpot** or a **fromSpot**. Any port properties should remain on the port element. Note that your adaptation of the `PortShiftingTool` will no longer be moving ports but only moving the TextBlocks within the new item Panels.

Comment: Sounds nice. I'll try to fiddle around with the alignment so that the port itself will always stick to the bottom of the item (and the top of the node). Any recommendation this issue?